# Method/Function Appears as Variable in IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

so I've been working on a simple thing to play around with, here is a snippet of code I made;

```
var person = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.fullName = () => `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}
```

Now if I type out the `fullName()` method of the object, it displays like this;

[image: Hmm]

Instead of displaying as a method, it displays as a variable, this also happens to the "person" object, is there any way to override the IntelliSense to get it to display properly?

Comment: It doesn't display as a "variable", it displays as a *property* which is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just small note about the difference between functions and methods:

Methods are related to Classes, while Functions are not. Since JavaScript is multi-paradigm (one of these being functional), most JavaScript functions are just that - functions. All Methods are Functions, but not all Functions are Methods.

On to your question, it has a simple answer: Lambdas (arrow notation) aren't classified as functions, so they'll display as variables/properties.

Hope this hepled!

Comment: Is there a way for them to be classified as a function though?

Comment: Other than editing IntelliSense's logic? Unfortunately not. Lambdas technically aren't functions, so they'll never be identified as such. But it really shouldn't be that big of a problem - lambdas don't take attributes or parameters, so there's no real need for that function of IntelliSense. If it's a case of wanting to easily identify them as functions, simply prefix them with a specific character or identifier. For example, `_fullName`, `FullName`, `F_fullName`, `func_FullName`, etc. Sorry this isn't the answer you were hoping for!

Comment: The problem is, even though it doesn't take any arguments, [it doesn't run](https://i.imgur.com/EaCuaaE.png) without having `()` at the end of it.

Comment: In JavaScript, if a Lambda takes no parameters or arguments, it the `()` - just a quirk of the language. Is there any specific reason you want the lambda to be recognised as a function? Other than for vanity reasons while coding, it serves little to no practical purpose. If I understand your need for it to be classified as a function we can work through and get an answer for you! :)

Comment: It's okay, I just find it kind of irritating that I don't know if I need to use it as a function or just a regular variable.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned an arrow function to the property. You may be able to get the behavior you want using the new keyword. I'm not certain though my knowledge about constructors has faded since We were told to stop using them 5 years or so ago.